# Chrome extension - Website not working after the script file is injected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on chrome extension for my personal use to fill a form on a specific website. I got everything working except after the injected file fills the form, the website that has the form stop working, I don’t know why.

manifest.json

```
    {
  "browser_action": {
  "browser_style": true,
  "default_title": "Fill FORM ON WEBSITE",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "description": "Fill FORM ON WEBSITE",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Fill FORM ON WEBSITE",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" , "file:///*"
  ],
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

---

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <label>Item Name</label><input type="text" id="itemnametxt"/><br>
    <label>Item Code</label><input type="text" id="itemcodetxt"/><br>
    <label>Date Of Input</label><input type="text"   
    id="dateofinouttxt"/><br>
    <button id="fillform"> Fill the form </button><br>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

popup.js

```
 $("#fillform").click(function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({ }, function (tabs) {
    var item_name = document.getElementById("itemnametxt").value ;
    var item_code = document.getElementById("itemcodetxt").value ;
    var item_date_input=document.getElementById("dateofinouttxt").value;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "fill.js",   
    runAt:"document_end", allFrames : true}, function(result){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {scriptOptions:  
    {param1:item_name, param2:item_code,param3:item_date_input}}, 
    function(){             alert(result[0]) ;});});
    });
    });
```

fill.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender,           
    sendResponse){var scriptOptions = message.scriptOptions;
    document.getElementById("itemContentID").value=scriptOptions.param1;
    document.getElementById("itemContntcode").value=scriptOptions.param2;
    document.getElementById("itemContentdoi").value=scriptOptions.param3;
    sendResponse({});
    });
```

---

when i work on the website after the form is filled , website not
working. I hope someone can find out what's wrong or anyone has
another way to fill form on a specific website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it should be `message.scriptOptions.paramN` instead of just `scriptOptions.paramN`

Comment: @user3003395, what do you mean "stop working"? Assuming you see no related errors in webpage console, it's possible that the values you assign are invalid for the form. Does your code change the values successfully?

Comment: yes my code change the values successfully. after that i can't submit or click anything in website.

Comment: You are using `chrome.tabs.query({ },...`. This will get a list of *all tabs* in Chrome. You are then using `tabs[0]` as the tab to inject your script. This will result in your script being injected into some semi-random tab. Assuming you want to inject into the tab the user is currently looking at, you should be using `chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},...`.

Comment: thank you Makyen for your response. your opinion is correct but this is not the problem because i always put my website tabs[0]. as i said in comment above my code change the values successfully after that i can't submit or click anything in website.

Comment: Try execCommand: `document.getElementById("itemContentID").focus(); document.execCommand('selectAll'); document.execCommand('insertText', false, scriptOptions.param1);`

Comment: Thank you wOxxOm  for your comment. I solved the problem by replacing injected file with content script. popup.js save param1, param2 ... into chrome storage. Then contentscript.js has chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener to receive the params. now the extension works successfully. Thank you again